# Few errors occured when training the facial expression recognition model

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network, face-recognition, training-data

I am working on a project to recognise facial expressions and  train the facial expression recognition model by using convolutional neural network(CNN). In this project, I am using **`Tensorflow 2.4 version`** and **`Python 3.8.8 version`**

**The output:**

```
Found 18282 images belonging to 5 classes.
Found 7178 images belonging to 7 classes.
```

**Below is the error that I got:**

```
2023-01-11 00:09:29.625187: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
c:/Users/Documents/Bachelor of Computer Science/FYP/Code/Program/Backup Test/TrainEmotionDetector.py:53: UserWarning: `Model.fit_generator` is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Please use `Model.fit`, which supports generators.
  emotion_model_info = emotion_model.fit_generator(
Epoch 1/20
2023-01-11 00:09:31.756943: W tensorflow/tsl/framework/cpu_allocator_impl.cc:82] Allocation of 31719424 exceeds 10% of free system memory.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/Documents/Bachelor of Computer Science/FYP/Code/Program/Backup Test/TrainEmotionDetector.py", line 53, in <module>
    emotion_model_info = emotion_model.fit_generator(
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 2604, in fit_generator
    return self.fit(
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 70, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 52, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node 'categorical_crossentropy/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits' defined at (most recent call last):
    File "c:/Users/Documents/Code/Program/Backup Test/TrainEmotionDetector.py", line 53, in <module>
      emotion_model_info = emotion_model.fit_generator(
    File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 2604, in fit_generator
      return self.fit(
    File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 65, in error_handler
      return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1650, in fit
      tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
    File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1249, in train_function
      return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1233, in step_function
      outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1222, in run_step
      outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1024, in train_step
      loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1082, in compute_loss
      return self.compiled_loss(
    File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\compile_utils.py", line 265, in __call__
      loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 152, in __call__
      losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 284, in call
      return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\losses.py", line 2004, in categorical_crossentropy
      return backend.categorical_crossentropy(
    File "C:\Users\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend.py", line 5538, in categorical_crossentropy
      return tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
Node: 'categorical_crossentropy/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits'
logits and labels must be broadcastable: logits_size=[64,7] labels_size=[64,5]
         [[{{node categorical_crossentropy/softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1181]
2023-01-11 00:09:32.976764: W tensorflow/core/kernels/data/generator_dataset_op.cc:108] Error occurred when finalizing GeneratorDataset iterator: FAILED_PRECONDITION: Python interpreter state is not initialized. The process may be terminated.
         [[{{node PyFunc}}]]
```

---

**Below is the full code:**

```
# import required packages
import cv2
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

# Initialize image data generator with rescaling
train_data_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
validation_data_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

# Preprocess all test images
train_generator = train_data_gen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/train',
        target_size=(48, 48),
        batch_size=64,
        color_mode="grayscale",
        class_mode='categorical')

# Preprocess all train images
validation_generator = validation_data_gen.flow_from_directory(
        'data/test',
        target_size=(48, 48),
        batch_size=64,
        color_mode="grayscale",
        class_mode='categorical')

# create model structure
emotion_model = Sequential()

emotion_model.add(Conv2D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(48, 48, 1)))
emotion_model.add(Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
emotion_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
emotion_model.add(Dropout(0.25))

emotion_model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
emotion_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
emotion_model.add(Conv2D(128, kernel_size=(3, 3), activation='relu'))
emotion_model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
emotion_model.add(Dropout(0.25))

emotion_model.add(Flatten())
emotion_model.add(Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
emotion_model.add(Dropout(0.5))
emotion_model.add(Dense(7, activation='softmax'))

cv2.ocl.setUseOpenCL(False)

emotion_model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(learning_rate=0.0001, decay=1e-6), metrics=['accuracy'])

# Train the neural network/model
emotion_model_info = emotion_model.fit_generator(
        train_generator,
        steps_per_epoch=28709 // 64,
        epochs=20,
        validation_data=validation_generator,
        validation_steps=7178 // 64)

# save model structure in jason file
model_json = emotion_model.to_json()
with open("model/emotion_model.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)

# save trained model weight in .h5 file
emotion_model.save_weights('model/emotion_model.h5')
```

I have upgraded the tensorflow to the latest version by using `pip install --upgrade tensorflow` but nothing works. It is expected to write the saved model into the **emotion_model.json** and **emotion_model.h5**. Please help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> logits and labels must be broadcastable:
> logits_size=[64,7] labels_size=[64,5]
> ```

Well, you kind of gave it away when you mentioned
the first set of images had just 5 distinct labels
while the next set had 7.

Prune two of those label classes and you'll be back in business.

Comment: I did realised this error but how do I know which line of code should be corrected?